# Mouse click not working properly, how to fix or diagnose what's wrong

Tags: windows, mouse, wireless-mouse

Bought Microsoft wireless mouse 3500 last month working fine, but since yesterday the right click is not working and sometimes left click does the right click functions.
I have plug, unplug several times, uninstall and install intellipoint software, changes usb ports, but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your mouse is broken and you should be able to get a refund/replacement.

But before you do that there is a few things you can try to diagnose the problem.

- Reinstall drivers *(as you have done)*
- Try it on another computer *(It should work without any need to install drivers, you just dont get the fancy bits. Normal pointing and clicking should work)*
- Change/charge the batteries in the mouse *(this is* **very** *unlikely to make any difference)*
- Boot from a [live cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) and see if it works on another OS

Answer (score 0):

Since the left click sometimes has the right click functions, I think the diagnosis is a driver problem.

The fix would be to [update the driver](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/wireless-mobile-mouse-3500/GMF-00010#support), or use a different one that does work.

Call MS Tech Support They will help make sure you installed it correctly.
If that fails, get it replaced, or ask for a refund.

These mice come with 90 tech support from day of 1st incident which would start when
you contact Microsoft at the below number.

MS Hardware Support and Warranty Claims

Tech Support 1-800-936-5700 for MS Hardware